How can we revert particular commit in local from bunch of commits?
Requirement: Revert particular commit in local by commit ID.
Description:

I have a branch cloned in my local from some repo.
I made some changes and committed time to time (Not pushed)

E.g.

Made some changes and committed. i.e. Commit ID: xyz-1
Made some changes and committed. i.e. Commit ID: xyz-2
Made some changes and committed. i.e. Commit ID: xyz-3
Made some changes and committed. i.e. Commit ID: xyz-4

Goal: Need to revert "xyz-2 and xyz-3" but "xyz-1 and xyz-4" will stay as it is.

Using git revert in this context seems inappropriate, since according to you all this is unpushed local history. You'd be better off getting rid (probably via interactive rebase) of these commits while they're not yet shared. (That being said, @dani-vta's answer is technically correct)

Romain's answer is even more appropriate for a cleaner history. +1

If you need to revert only the commits xyz-2 and xyz-3, just execute git revert with the commit's SHA1 supplied in reverse chronological order. In fact, since you're reverting your changes, starting from your latest commits will most likely result in fewer conflicts, making the revert easier to manage and the history more readable. Thanks to @RomainValeri for pointing that out in the comments.

Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

git revert xyz-3 xyz-2

In particular, check the section commit, which states

Commits to revert. For a more complete list of ways to spell commit names, see gitrevisions[7]. Sets of commits can also be given but no traversal is done by default, see git-rev-list[1] and its --no-walk option.


Another detail: commits should be reverted in reverse chronological order, it's a lot less conflict-prone since you're removing first what was added last. So it would be git revert xyz-3 xyz-2

Thank you both for your answers and support! It is the way but on a general note for all, you may face conflict while reverting commit from the middle. Take care to resolve it.

I'm not sure if you mean revert precisely or just to mean "I don't want that commit".
Maybe a rebase would work for you.
git rebase --interactive HEAD~4

or
git rebase --interactive coommit-before-xyz-1

You could then mark the commit to be dropped:
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
#
(...)
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.

As with any operation that rewrites history, be careful. If this was a shared repo and your colleagues already had the latest changes git revert would be in almost all cases be better.
